# Tornado user authentication

Tags: authentication, tornado, credentials

I have a set of **APIs** and each one is a subclass of a **BaseRequestHandler**. Within this **BaseRequestHandler** I'm going to set a *self.user* variable with a dictionary containing all user's credentials as value.

For example:

```
self.user = {
    "id": 0,
    "ip": "user ip",
    "country_name": "user country name",
    ...
}
```

My problem is that if the first incoming request to one of my set of APIs is not complete, the second incoming request to another API will override the *user* credentials, so I have a mismatch of the user's credentials in the first incoming request when I need to use those credentials.

In other words, in the **first** request I have the user's credentials of the **second** incoming request.

How can I track each incoming request to avoid the user's credentials mismatch?

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Within our project we have more than one level of subclassing and we've implemented an asynchronous multiprocessing web server.

Inside the `Application` instance we have a list of APIs like these:

```
application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/api1/info1", api1.InfoOneRequestHandler),
    (r"/api1/info2", api1.InfoTwoRequestHandler),
    (r"/api2/info1", api2.InfoOneRequestHandler),
    (r"/api3/info1", api3.InfoOneRequestHandler)
])
```

Each one of these exposed APIs are subclasses and for each one of them we have a specific super-class named: `BaseAPIOneRequestHandler`, `BaseAPITwoRequestHandler`, `BaseAPIThreeRequestHandler`.

These super-classes (`BaseAPIOneRequestHandler`, `APITwoBaseRequestHandler`, `BaseAPIThreeRequestHandler`) are subclasses as well , and they all inherit the main (shared) super-class named `BaseAPIRequestHandler`.

`BaseAPIRequestHandler` contains a method to retrieve permissions and privileges for a specific `User Id` who's calling that specific API.

```
@tornado.gen.coroutine
def _retrieve_user_info(self, user_id):
    self.user["id"] = ...
    self.user["country_name"] = ...
    self.user["country_code"] = ...
    ... POPULATE DATA ...
```

Inside each one of the subclasses (`BaseAPIOneRequestHandler`, `BaseAPITwoRequestHandler`, `BaseAPIThreeRequestHandler`) we call the method:

```
_request = tornado.escape.json_decode(self.request.body)
yield self._retrieve_user_info(_request["user_id"])
```

The logic is more or less the following:

```
application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/api1/info1", api1.InfoOneRequestHandler),
    (r"/api1/info2", api1.InfoTwoRequestHandler),
    (r"/api2/info1", api2.InfoOneRequestHandler),
    (r"/api3/info1", api3.InfoOneRequestHandler)
])

class InfoOneRequestHandler(BaseAPIOneRequestHandler):
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        The problem occurs within this method when we're going to 
        retrieve information about the user.
        """
        ... PERFORM OTHER INSTRUCTIONS ...

        # _id variable will contain the ID of the user who's calling
        # another API (it override the key "id" of the user
        # who's calling the first API).
        # When two users are calling two different APIs, both "id"
        # keys will contain the ID of second user
        _id = self.user["id"]

        ... REMAINING OPERATIONS ...

class BaseAPIOneRequestHandler(BaseAPIRequestHandler):
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def prepare(self):
        """
        Here we're going to call the method to update the user's
        credentials.
        """
        super(BaseAPIOneRequestHandler, self).prepare()

        ... OTHER LOCAL THINGS ...

        _request = tornado.escape.json_decode(self.request.body)
        yield self._retrieve_user_info(_request["user_id"])

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def on_finish(self):
        ... API ONE LOCAL THINGS ...

        super(BaseAPIOneRequestHandler, self).on_finish()

class BaseAPIRequestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def prepare(self):
        ... POPULATE GLOBAL DATA ...

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.write("Method not allowed")

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def _retrieve_user_info(self, user_id):
        """
        Here we're going to update the user's information base on the 
        user's identifier (user_id).
        """
        self.user["id"] = ...
        self.user["country_name"] = ...
        self.user["country_code"] = ...

        ... POPULATE USER DATA ...

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def options(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", self.request.headers["Access-Control-Request-Headers"])
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", self.request.headers["Access-Control-Request-Method"])
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

    def on_finish(self):
        self.user = None
```

Comment: Each request creates a new `RequestHandler` instance and therefore a new `self` object. There shouldn't be any way for one request to affect another from the code you've shown so far; can you add more detail about what exactly you're doing?

Comment: Hi @BenDarnell, thank you for your comment.
I've updated my question with more details, please take a look at the **EDIT** section. Thank you very much!

Comment: I still don't understand how things are going wrong. What are the two requests and what exactly is happening?

Comment: The problem arises when somebody calls /api1/info1 and shortly after /api1/info2 (for instance, that happen with calls to other APIs as well). During the first call to /api1/info1  our _retrieve_user_info() method fills the User ID data into self.user dictionary.  The same happen when the following call to /api/info2 happens. The problem is that the second call overwrites the self.user filled by the first API call. When the two calls end, both self.user dictionaries contain the User ID data of the second user who called info2.

Comment: using name `type` as a classname is considerable harmful and error prone

Comment: Your final code snippet can't work: you've got things out of order and refer to them before they're defined. What's in your *real* code? If you have `class api1(type):` before `class type(RequestHandler)`, then `api1` is a metaclass instead of a regular class, and things get very strange indeed. I think that might be enough to explain the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Sorry guys for the poor explanation about the code, I've changed some snippet of codes to better understand what is my problem.